# Payments from Business account to Personal account using REST API

Tags: paypal

I have configured my PHP application to accept Paypal payments using the REST API. In this way the things are working ok, and i can see the payments in the sandbox environment.

But i also need to do payments from my business account to a different paypal account using the receiver email account.

Can i use the REST API to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the REST API currently does not allow configuring the receiver for payments or send money to another PayPal account, although those features could be supported in the future. If you need to send money to a different paypal account, you need to get client_id and client_secret from developer.paypal.com using that paypal account and use the id/secret pair in your application.

The other options you have are to use Paypal Adaptive Payments or MassPAY API which allows for payments to be sent to multiple parties.

Answer (score 0):

i have finally used the "*PHP Paypal Merchant SDK*" to do the payments from the Business account to the Personal accounts using the receiving email.

I got confused at first because in the GitHub repository (https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php/tree/namespace-php5.3) appears this advert message:

**"This SDK is deprecated. It is strongly recommended that new implementations use the PHP Rest SDK"**

Thanks!